# How to reduce boilerplate for iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

Mainly as an exercise I am implementing a conversion from base `B` to base `10`:

```
unsigned fromBaseB(std::vector<unsigned> x,unsigned b){
    unsigned out = 0;
    unsigned pow = 1;
    for (size_t i=0;i<x.size();i++){
        out += pow * x[i];
        pow *= b;
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    auto z = std::vector<unsigned>(9,0);
    z[3] = 1;
    std::cout << fromBaseB(z,3) << std::endl;
}
```

Now I would like to write this using algorithms. E.g. using `accumulate` I could write

```
unsigned fromBaseB2(std::vector<unsigned> x,unsigned b){
    unsigned pow = 1;
    return std::accumulate(x.begin(),
                           x.end(),0u,
                           [pow,b](unsigned sum,unsigned v) mutable {
                                unsigned out = pow*v;
                                pow *= b;
                                return out+sum;
                           });
}
```

However, imho thats not nicer code at all. Actually it would be more natural to write it as an inner product, because thats just what we have to calculate to make the basis transformation. But to use `inner_product` I need an iterator:

```
template <typename T> struct pow_iterator{
    typedef T value_type;
    pow_iterator(T base) : base(base),value(1) {}
    T base,value;
    pow_iterator& operator++(){ value *= base;return *this; }
    T operator*() {return value; }
    bool operator==(const pow_iterator& other) const { return value == other.value;}
};

unsigned fromBaseB3(std::vector<unsigned> x,unsigned b){
    return std::inner_product(x.begin(),x.end(),pow_iterator<unsigned>(b),0u);
}
```

Using that iterator, now calling the algorithm is nice an clean, but I had to write a lot of boilerplate code for the iterator. Maybe it is just my misunderstanding of how algorithms and iterators are supposed to be used... Actually this is just an example of a general problem I am facing sometimes: I have a sequence of numbers that is calculated based on a simple pattern and I would like to have a iterator that when dereferenced returns the corresponding number from that sequence. When the sequence is stored in a container I simply use the iterators provided by the container, but I would like to do the same, also when there is no container where the values are stored. I could of course try to write my own generic iterator that does the job, but isnt there something existing in the standard library that can help here?

To me it feels a bit strange, that I can use a lambda to cheat `accumulate` into calculating an inner product, but to use `inner_product` directly I have to do something extra (either precalculate the powers and store them in a container, or write an iterator ie. a seperate `class`).

**tl;dr: Is there a easy way to reduce the boilerplate for the `pow_iterator` above?**

the more general (but maybe too broad) question: Is it "ok" to use an iterator for a sequence of values that is not stored in a container, but that is calculated only if the iterator is dereferenced? Is there a "C++ way" of implementing it?

Comment: look at the boost.iterator library. Specifically iterator_adapter and iterator_facade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard Hodges wrote in the comments, you can look at [`boost::iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/iterator/doc/). Alternatively, there is [`range-v3`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3). If you go with boost, there are a few possible ways to go. The following shows how to do so with [`boost::iterator::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/example/counting_iterator_example.cpp) and [`boost::iterator::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) (C++ 11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>                                                                                           

int main() {
    const std::size_t base = 2;
    auto make_it = [](std::size_t i) {
        return boost::make_transform_iterator(
            boost::make_counting_iterator(i),
            [](std::size_t j){return std::pow(base, j);});};
    for(auto b = make_it(0); b != make_it(10); ++b)
        std::cout << *b << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
```

Comment: You do realize you just added a mountain of boilerplate from Boost, right? :-)